# hide or show (view link ) was not working as expected when the user attach file using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

With my current code the user can attach the file and the file name will be shown in the textfield and view link will appear, if the user clicks the view link it will open in the new page.

My issue was the view link was displayed in the second attachment row but it should only when the user attaches the file then view link should be displayed not before that.

Second one if the user click the accept tick the attachment should be disabled I have css class for the disabled button:

```
.cst_select_dis{
    background-color: #b9b9b9;
    color: #fff;    
    border-bottom:2px solid #000;
    width: 91px;
    height: 25px;
    border-left:0px;
    border-right:0px;
    border-top:0px;
    margin-left:20px;
}
```

Here is the current jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var $preview = $(".preview");
    $preview.hide();

    $(".checkfile").on("change", function(){     
        var filename = this.value;
        var files = this.files;
        var URL = window.URL||window.webkitURL;
        var url = URL.createObjectURL(files[0]);
        $preview.attr("href", url);
        $preview.show();
        //$acceptdiv.show();
        document.getElementById('file_name').value = filename;
        $("#file_name").prop("disabled", true);
    });

    $(document).on('click', ".accpt_chk", function () {
        if ($('.accpt_chk').is(':checked')) {
            $('.checkfile').attr('disabled', 'true');
            $('.cst_select ').addClass("cst_select_dis");
        } else {
            $('.checkfile').removeAttr('disabled')
            $('.checkfile').prop('enabled', false);
            $('.cst_select ').removeClass("cst_select_dis");
            //$('#btn_selct').hasClass('.cst_select ').remove().addClass('.cst_select_dis');
        }
        //$('.qq-upload-button').prop('disabled', !this.checked);
    });

    $('.checkfile').on('change', function (e) {
        myfile = $(this).val();    
        var ext = myfile.split('.').pop();
        if (ext == "pdf" || ext == "jpeg") {
            $(file_name).val(myfile);
        } else {
            alert('Invalid File Type')
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        if(e.currentTarget.files[0].size>=1024*1024*5) {
            alert('File Size cannot be more than 5 MB')
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
});
```

Kindly please suggest me.

Here is the fiddle [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/karthic2914/d4hh5t34/)

Comment: Confirm `$preview.show();` is running by adding a `console.log()` above it. Or use the debugger.

Comment: @AdrianLynch do i need to put some condition

Comment: Are you trying to work out why `$preview.show();` isn't doing what you want? If so, you need to confirm it's actually getting to that point. It might not be. Log anything to the console to prove you're getting where you need.

Comment: @AdrianLynch i checked in the log view link was show can you please tell me how to hide if there is no file attached

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check inline comments for detailed explanation and **[DEMO here](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/d4hh5t34/1/)**

```
$(".checkfile").on("change", function(){     
     var filename = this.value;
     var files = this.files;
     var URL = window.URL||window.webkitURL;
     var url = URL.createObjectURL(files[0]);
     $(this).closest('.row').find('.preview').attr("href", url).show();
     //get current group's preview element using $(this) and add show in same line
     document.getElementById('file_name').value = filename;
     $("#file_name").prop("disabled", true);
});
//your checkbox class is not accpt_chk instead it is lbl_chk_acpt_right and so click event was not firing
$(document).on('click', ".lbl_chk_acpt_right", function () {
     if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
          $(this).closest('.row').find('.checkfile').attr('disabled', true);
          $(this).closest('.row').find('.cst_select ').addClass("cst_select_dis");
          //again get the element to disable using $(this)
     } else {
          $(this).closest('.row').find('.checkfile').removeAttr('disabled')
          $(this).closest('.row').find('.cst_select ').removeClass("cst_select_dis");
     }
});
```

---

**UPDATE**

**[Updated DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/d4hh5t34/4/)**

There were many error in the code when I analyzed and I can stress on important 2 or 3 mistakes which are as below:

> - You have written `onchange` event for `.checkfile` twice which is unnecessary
> - You have give same `id` to different inputs `#file_name` which is a serious error and breaks HTML rules as there should be unique `id`s in the `DOM`. So I have made use of `.check` class of that `input element`
> - Whenever you refer an element of a group try referring it with `$(this)` so that you will target the proper element.

**Added some inline comments too**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $preview = $(".preview");    
    $preview.hide();
    $(".checkfile").on("change", function(){     
        var filename = this.value;
        var files = this.files;
        var URL = window.URL||window.webkitURL;
        var url = URL.createObjectURL(files[0]);
        $(this).closest('.row').find('.preview').attr("href", url).show();
        $(this).next('.check').prop("disabled", true);
        var myfile = $(this).val();    
        var ext = myfile.split('.').pop();
        if (ext == "pdf" || ext == "jpeg" || ext=="jpg") {
            $(this).next('.check').val(filename);
            //again get the next element of input type=file with $(this)
            //$(this) refers to current element and here its .checkfile element
        } else {
            $(this).closest('.row').find('.preview').hide()
            alert('Invalid File Type')
            $(this).next('.check').val('');
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        if(e.currentTarget.files[0].size>=1024*1024*5)
        { 
            alert('File Size cannot be more than 5 MB')
            e.preventDefault();
            $(this).closest('.row').find('.preview').hide()
            //hide view link here too
        }
    });
    $(document).on('click', ".lbl_chk_acpt_right", function () {
        if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
            $(this).closest('.row').find('.checkfile').attr('disabled', true);
            $(this).closest('.row').find('.cst_select ').addClass("cst_select_dis");
        } else {
            $(this).closest('.row').find('.checkfile').removeAttr('disabled')
            $(this).closest('.row').find('.cst_select ').removeClass("cst_select_dis");
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: thanks for your support but each and every time the alert was coming invalid type this has to accept only pdf and jpeg jpg format not all :)

Comment: do i need to check any validation over there

Comment: the disabled was working perfectly fine but only problem is with file upload

Comment: sorry @Guruprasad sure i will wait

Comment: any luck I waiting for your valuable response

Comment: thank you so much sure i will check and let you know

Comment: everything works fine but one small issue once user upload png format (non support format) getting an alert but the view link was there do i need to put condition to remove this

Comment: Thanks for putting the explanation

Comment: Anytime.. Do not forget to correct it in your code.. Happy coding.. :)

Comment: Thanks for the excellent comments will sure definitely i will take

Comment: One small request there was an error ReferenceError: e is not defined

Comment: do i need to set a varable for e

Comment: where you are getting it??

Comment: when trying to upload the file

Comment: `$(".checkfile").on("change", function(e){` Add `e` inside the `function` here.. It is basically to capture the `event` and here it is `change event`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/90393/discussion-between-mahadevan-and-guruprasad-rao).